# How do I resolve error 500 when invoking REST webservice through REST Client code?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jersey, handler

I am getting the below exception when I try to invoke the REST webservice through the REST Client code:

> Error 500: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException:
>   Handler processing failed;
>   nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig

When I run in debug mode the following line of code gives me the above exception:

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
```

I tried to put all my Spring jars into the *web-inf* folder, but I'm still facing this issue.

Comment: Which version of jersey client jar do you have? Have you added the jar correctly in your classpath?

Comment: Am using jersey-bundle-1.9.1.jar. Yes I have added the jars correctly , am not getting any compliation errors. In other words I wanted to consume mainframe hosted REST webserviece through Spring!

Comment: are you using Maven? If so, the jar might be in `provided` scope, which loosely (and unformally) means: "Use the jar while compiling, then discard it when you build the deployable package. The container is supposed to provide the JAR in other ways". In this case, add the JAR to your container or, easier, change the dependecy scope to `compile`